# Why does my timer hook not update it's internal state?

Tags: react-hooks

**For some reason my timer is not updating it's internal Timer State after I modify the input field.  Here is the intial state of my page and State.**

[image: Initial State]

**This is what my screen and state look like after I modify the input from 10 to 8 seconds. Notice that the Timer State does not update**

[image: Timer state not updating]

Here is my code for the workout page:

```
function WorkoutPage(props: any) {

const DEFAULT_SECONDS_BETWEEN_REPS: number = 10
const [secondsBetweenRepsSetting, setSecondsBetweenRepsSetting] = useState(DEFAULT_SECONDS_BETWEEN_REPS)
const {secondsLeft, isRunning, start, stop} = useTimer({
        duration: secondsBetweenRepsSetting,
        onExpire: () => sayRandomExerciseName(),
        onTick: () => handleTick(),
    })
const onTimeBetweenRepsChange = (event: any) => {
        const secondsBetweenRepsSettingString = event.target.value;
        const secondsBetweenRepsSettingInt = parseInt(secondsBetweenRepsSettingString)
        setSecondsBetweenRepsSetting(secondsBetweenRepsSettingInt)
    }

return <React.Fragment>
<input type="number" name="secondsBetweenRepsSetting" value={secondsBetweenRepsSetting} onChange={onTimeBetweenRepsChange}/>
</React.Fragment>

}
```

Here is my useTimer Class:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Validate from "../utils/Validate";
import useInterval from "./useInterval";

export default function useTimer({ duration: timerDuration, onExpire, onTick}) {
  const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(timerDuration)
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false)

  function start() {
    setIsRunning(true)
  }
  function stop() {
    setIsRunning(false)
  }

  function handleExpire() {
    Validate.onExpire(onExpire) && onExpire();
  }

  useInterval(() => {
    const secondsMinusOne = secondsLeft - 1;
    setSecondsLeft(secondsMinusOne)
    if(secondsMinusOne <= 0) {
      setSecondsLeft(timerDuration) // Reset timer automatically
      handleExpire()
    } else {
      Validate.onTick(onTick) && onTick();
    }
  }, isRunning ? 1000 : null)

  return {secondsLeft, isRunning, start, stop, }
}
```

My full codebase is here in case someone is interested: https://github.com/kamilski81/bdt-coach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events you expect:

- User changes the input
- The change handler fires and calls `setSecondsBetweenRepsSetting` with the new value
- The component re-renders with the new value for `secondsBetweenRepsSetting`
- `useTimer` is invoked with a `duration` property of the new value
- The `secondsLeft` state in the `useTimer` hook changes to the new `duration` value **<-- oops! this does not happen**

Why doesn't this last item happen? Because within the `useTimer` implementation, the only place you use the duration is as the *initial* value of `secondsLeft`. Calling the hook a second time with a new duration value will not change the `secondsLeft` state, and this is by design.

My recommendation would be to include `setSecondsLeft` in the return value of the `useTimer` hook to give you a way to override the time left in the timer. You could then use `setSecondsLeft` directly in the input change handler:

```js
const { secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft, isRunning, start, stop } = useTimer({
  duration: secondsBetweenRepsSetting,
  onExpire: () => sayRandomExerciseName(),
  onTick: () => handleTick(),
});

const onTimeBetweenRepsChange = (event: any) => {
  const secondsBetweenRepsSettingString = event.target.value;
  const secondsBetweenRepsSettingInt = parseInt(
    secondsBetweenRepsSettingString
  );
  setSecondsBetweenRepsSetting(secondsBetweenRepsSettingInt);
  setSecondsLeft(secondsBetweenRepsSettingInt);
};
```